# Audio null in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-source, audioclip

I am getting this weird error in unity when I am trying to run my (sad excuse for a) game. Here's the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ARsound : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static AudioClip sound;
    static AudioSource audioSrc;


    void Start()
    {
        sound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("AR SFX");
        audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public static void playSound()
    {
        audioSrc.PlayOneShot(sound);
    }


}
```

And the error is this:

> PlayOneShot was played with a null audio clip

Even though that audio clip doesn't SEEM to be null.
Here is some additional info:

> Gun:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/Gun.cs:17)

Suggestions?

Comment: There is no `while` loop here. It's also not at all clear how your question title matches your question body.

Comment: Where is the while loop !!?

Comment: I didn't mean while loop. Oh no! That was from a different question I was going to ask. It's 3 A.M. So I'm kinda tired. I'm SO sorry. I changed the title to what I wanted it to be.

Comment: Have you considered that `Resources.Load<AudioClip>("AR SFX");` failed so `sound` is simpy `null`? The additional info `Gun:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/Gun.cs:17)` doesn't help at all since I think this is just the place where you are calling `ARSound.playSound();` ...

Comment: I figured it out! I did it a little differently. First I declared two audio sources ```public AudioSource shootSound; public AudioSource shootFastSound;   ```Then, I did ```shootSound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
shootFastSound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();```    And lastly, I did ```private void ShootFast()                                                                    {
        shootFastSound.Play();                                                                           // Other Code                         }

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `Resources.Load` returns null - this happens when the asset is not found (no exception).

See docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

So you need to make sure that the asset exists and that it can be loaded.